# How to use subsection numbering in the subsection title?

Tags: macros, sectioning, numbering

I want to use the number of a subsection in a document to create the subsection title, but be able to subtract one from the subsection number.

More specifically, in my document, subsection "1.1" is called "Base scenario", so I want subsection "1.2" to have the title "Scenario 1", subsection "1.3" to have the title "Scenario 2", etc...

For the moment I'm doing it manually but I'm wondering if there is a way of doing it automatically through a command.
Here is a MWE that summarizes what I am looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Base scenario}
\subsection{Scenario 1}
\label{subsec:Subsection}
I would like a command in the style of "\refSubSecMinusOne{subsec:Subsection}" to just return "1" (i.e. one minus the section number) so that I could use it in the title.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will your document typically have this setup? That is, each `\section` has a `Base scenario` `\subsection` as the *first* subsection, followed by one or more `\subsection`s titled `Scenario 1`, `Scenario 2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a suitable counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{scenario}[section]
\newcommand{\scenario}{\stepcounter{scenario}\subsection{Scenario \thescenario}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Base scenario}

\scenario

\scenario

\section{Section B}

\subsection{Base scenario}

\scenario

\scenario

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, and it's an elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Base scenario}
\subsection{Scenario \the\numexpr\value{subsection}-1\relax}
\label{subsec:Subsection}

\end{document}
```